# Are asterisks in /etc/hosts supposed to have any effect?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, hosts

I have something like this in `/etc/hosts`:

> 192.168.0.1 example.com
>
> 192.168.0.1 *.example.com

`example.com` is pinged to `192.168.0.1` as expected but pinging say `sub.example.com` outputs:

> unknown host sub.example.com

Comment: Did you try running `man hosts` from a terminal?

Comment: @cdhowie Yes, just now. `man hosts | grep '\(aster\|\*\)'` outputs nothing useful.

Comment: That's because the feature you're looking for doesn't exist. :)  (At least not without running your own DNS server.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have answered your own question!

The `/etc/hosts` file is a one-to-one mapping between a hostname (not a collection of them) to a particular IP address.

Consider putting this into `/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1 *.com
```

Comment: Not sure if I answered my own question which actually was more about how to map all subdomains of a domain to an IP address, not a TLD to an IP.

Comment: @DesmondHume - One works and the other does not.